# GIF image does not animate

Tags: animation, printing, gif

I am printing a .gif image through my printer, but it does not move like on my screen. it looks like I a jpeg format image.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make the assumption that this question is a joke.

You **cannot** print *.gif images in an animated fashion with a printer.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest printing each individual frame of the animated GIF on a single piece of paper.

By flipping through them from the first page till the last, it would indeed appear like the animated GIF on your computer.